# Is $\langle \phi_m|\dot{\phi}_n\rangle$ assumed real in electronic excitation theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, quantum-states

I'm studying a topic of the Nikitin's [book](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gwhr1qn2rw946gv/%5BNikitin_1974%5D_Theory_of_Elementary_Atomic_and_Molecular_Processes_in_Gases.pdf?dl=0) (see pages 101 and 105) which deals with nonadiabatic electronic transitions, considering the two-state approximation. I think that the author make assumptions in its mathematical derivations which aren't even mentioned neither explained in the text. Maybe the assumptions are so trivial that the author doesn't feel the need to explain them. But I got some doubts.

Basically there are two equations that matter in this context: the Schrodinger equation $(14.5)$, and the expansion of the wave function in the diabatic basis (which is orthonormal) $(14.4)$:

$$i\hbar\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}(\mathbf{r},t)=H[\mathbf{r},\mathbf{R}(t)]\Psi(\mathbf{r},t)\tag{14.5}$$

$$\Psi(\mathbf{r},t)=\sum_m b_m(t)e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int^tH_{mm}(\mathrm{R})\,dt}\phi_m^0(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{R})\tag{14.4}$$

where $\mathbf{r}$ is the set of the electrons coordinates and $\mathbf{R}$ is the set of the nuclei coordinates of the system. Note that $\mathbf{R}=\mathbf{R}(t)$ (the nuclei are treated classically). And $H_{nm}(\mathbf{R})=\langle\phi_n^0|H|\phi_m^0\rangle$ correspond to the $(n,m)$ entry of the Hamiltonian matrix, $[H]$.

By substituting $(14.4)$ in (14.5), multiplying by $\phi_n^0(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{R})$ and integrating in the electrons coordinates, one would get:

$$i\hbar\dot{b}_n=-H_{nn}b_n+\sum_m\left(H_{nm}-i\hbar\langle\phi_n^0|\dot{\phi_m^0}\rangle\right)e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int^t\left(H_{mm}-H_{nn}\right)\,dt}b_m \tag{i}$$

And by using the two-state approximation (i.e. truncating the series in $(14.4)$ to two terms, $m=1,2$), the equation $(i)$ becomes:

> $$i\hbar\dot{b}_1(t)=-i\hbar\langle\phi_1^0|\dot{\phi_1^0}\rangle b_1+\left(H_{12}-i\hbar\langle\phi_1^0|\dot{\phi_2^0}\rangle \right)e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int^t\left(H_{22}-H_{11}\right)\,dt}b_2 \tag{ii}$$
>
> $$i\hbar\dot{b}_2(t)=\left(H_{21}-i\hbar\langle\phi_2^0|\dot{\phi_1^0}\rangle \right)e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\int^t\left(H_{22}-H_{11}\right)\,dt}b_1-i\hbar\langle\phi_2^0|\dot{\phi_2^0}\rangle b_2 \tag{iii}$$

Nikitin got the following instead:

> $$i\hbar\dot{b}_1(t)=\left(H_{12}-i\hbar\langle\phi_1^0|\dot{\phi_2^0}\rangle \right)e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int^t\left(H_{22}-H_{11}\right)\,dt}b_2 \tag{14.16}$$
>
> $$i\hbar\dot{b}_2(t)=\left(H_{21}+i\hbar\langle\phi_1^0|\dot{\phi_2^0}\rangle \right)e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\int^t\left(H_{22}-H_{11}\right)\,dt}b_1 \tag{14.17}$$

Now, by comparing mine and Nikitin equations, I think that Nikitin considered the following assumption:

> $\langle \phi_n^0|\dot{\phi_m^0}\rangle $ is real. Since $\langle \phi_n^0|\dot{\phi_m^0}\rangle=-\langle \phi_m^0|\dot{\phi_n^0}\rangle^* $, the only way that $\langle \phi_m^0|\dot{\phi_n^0}\rangle^*=\langle \phi_m^0|\dot{\phi_n^0}\rangle$, is that if $\langle \phi_m^0|\dot{\phi_n^0}\rangle$ is real. Note that this also justifies that $\langle \phi_n^0|\dot{\phi_n^0}\rangle=0$

I don't know how to justify this assumption. When should it be made? Do you know any other book/papers that treat better the math involved in these equations?